# getting absolute path in c# for navigation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, server.mappath

I have created an MVC app in c#, It has different menus and sub-menus.
The problem I am facing is that of navigation ,
the routing link looks like this

```
http://localhost/menu/1
http://localhost/submenu/5
http://localhost/submenu3/1
```

I cant just hardcore links in the menu `href` , therefore I was looking for some command to give me absolute path that is `http://localhost` so that I can use that for making dynamic navigation, In PHP it was quite simpler by using `$_SERVER` variable but I am unable to fnd any function here.

```
Server.MapPath("/") gives me my local drive address where it is stored.
```

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: @RahulSingh Url.Content("/") returned nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is MVC application then use "~/ControllerName/Action" instead of trying to get the absolute path. I have used this below code in my project and it is working like a charm for me.

```
<a id="aprimA" href="~/Account/StartingorMaintaining">HOME</a>
```

Thanks,
Manas Sahu

My blog: http://justsharingfun.blogspot.com/

Comment: exactly, the idea from above smells like bad coding practice...
for one specific example - is okey, but in whole app - no dude, don't go this way :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to trouble yourself with the absolute path for generating links.

You should use the     [Url.Action(string actionName, string controllerName,Object routeValues)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460348%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)     method. If you have RouteValues then you can add them as an anonymous type using the third parameter.

E.G:

```
    Url.Action("Details","Widget",new {widgetId = 1})
```

which should generate something like:

```
    http://yourhost.com/Widget/Details/1
```

depending on how your routevalues are set up.

Answer (score 0):

try in this way

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/menu/1");
```

**update**

if it doesn't work you can try

```
HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/menu/1");
```

Usually in mvc applications I use

```
var url = Url.Content("~/menu/1");
```

otherwise if you call an action of a specific controlelr you can do

```
Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")
```